# How to specify different readme files for github and npm

Tags: github, npm, documentation, publish, readme

Both use the `README.md` as the description when you publish. A common practice is to use a single shared file.

But what if I need to have the different Readme and still publish it from a single local repo with no manual editing/replacement

PS

I tried to use `"readme": "npm-readme.md"` in package.json but it displays a value of this field, not the content of а file

Comment: Although not directly answering this question, it is also worth mentioning that also some repositories are monorepos (e.g., Jest) and they use the "repository.directory" field of the package.json file to break the repository into multiple packages, and then each of them will be able to have its own README.md file.

Comment: In this case, the problem can be the same - what shows GitHub in a package folder and what is shown on NPM page of this package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason zavr's answer (using `README` and `README.md`) didn't work when I tried it (probably the logic used by NPM has changed). But what did work is putting the GitHub README into `.github` directory (this is allowed according to their [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes)), and using the root `README.md` as the version for NPM along the lines of

```
<!-- README for NPM; the one for GitHub is in .github directory. -->

<badges>

<a brief description>

Please refer to the [GitHub README](https://github.com/<your repo>#readme) for full documentation.
```

Luckily, for GitHub `.github/README.md` seems to take priority over `README.md`.

Update 2021-02-06: a quick note about best practice. NPM wouldn't let you update the readme without bumping the package version, and in reality you often need to make updates, sometimes minor, to the docs. So I'd recommend to provide full docs in the GitHub readme, but still give a short description of the library on NPM, which in combination with `keywords` field of `package.json` will make the package more discoverable. It's also a good idea to include badges in the NPM readme because that will increase the quality score displayed by NPM (see discussion of "branding" score in this [article](https://itnext.io/increasing-an-npm-packages-search-score-fb557f859300)).

Comment: Awesome mate this is the final solution! Really works, proof https://www.npmjs.com/package/@usulpro/readme-pro

Answer (score 10):

Good question mate! I prefer GitHub to NPM for a number of reasons, such as

a) the column on NPM is to narrow and all tables start to scroll
b) there is no padding when images are aligned to left of right
c) the TOC navigation does not work because anchor links are generated differently on GitHub and npm

Therefore I found a solution: add a `README` file, which will be read by NPM, and keep `README.md` file which will be read by GitHub. Easy-peasy but no guarantee it will continue to work.

Comment: so npm will take README instead of README.md?

Comment: yeah this is an npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rqt/namecheap this is its github https://github.com/rqt/namecheap. You can try it on your package by publishing with a beta tag, e.g., yarn publish --tag beta

Comment: Great solution, mate! And damn simple! :)

Comment: @zavr — Good eye for pointing that out! Could you explain how jQuery did it? Their readme on npm is different than on github, but I can't find the npm readme file in the repo or in the gitignore. npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery/v/3.3.1 github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/3.3.1

Answer (score 7):

One solution can be to use two readme files and rename them using npm scripting during `npm publish`.

This can be done as follows.

On source control, we would have the following files:

- **`README.md`** - This is the default git readme where you would document your source.
- **`npm.README.md`** - This would be the readme that would be seen on NPM.

Next, we would have the following in `package.json` (note that some contents are omitted).

```
{
  ...    
  "scripts": {
    ... 
    "build": "...",
    "use:npmReadme": "mv 'README.md' 'git.README.md' && mv 'npm.README.md' 'README.md'",
    "use:gitReadme": "mv 'README.md' 'npm.README.md' && mv 'git.README.md' 'README.md'",
    "prepublishOnly": "run-s build use:npmReadme",
    "postpublish": "npm run use:gitReadme"
  }, 
  "dependencies": {
    ... 
  },
  "devDependencies": { 
    ... 
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2", 
    ...
  }
}
```

In **devDependencies**, the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package is used. This allows using the [run-s](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/master/docs/run-s.md) command to run specified npm scripts sequentially.

in the **scripts** section, we have the following scripts:

**Scripts to Rename README files**

- `use:npmReadme` - This simply backs up the current git specific readme, and then renames `npm.README.md` to be the default `README.md`.
- `use:gitReadme` - This simply reverts back to using the git specific readme as the default `README.md`.

**prepublishOnly**

This is executed BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, and ONLY on `npm publish`. (Does not run with `npm install`).

Here, the solution is built, and then we run `use:npmReadme`.

**postPublish**

This is executed AFTER the package is published on npm.

Here, we run `use:gitReadme` to revert the readme files back to their original state.

More information on prepublishOnly and postPublish can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Comment: Thank you. This solution is one of the obvious and straightforward, but it is not very far from manual renaming. I asked more about the possibility of setting this through the settings. So I can't accept this answer but sure it could be used as a solution in some specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

[keshav.bahadoor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987725/4988996) answer inspired me to use similar approach in GitHub workflows.

I'm using it as following:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  ...
  - run: mv NPM-README.md README.md
  ...
  - run: npm publish --access public
```

I'm moving `NPM-README.md` to `README.md` only during workflow and not committing.

rest of the [workflow yaml file](https://github.com/open-template-hub/server-generator/blob/develop/.github/workflows/release.yml)

Note: This is working for GitHub workflows, not makes sense to use in your local.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

1. *(the more good one)* If we named the `npm` readme to `README.md` and the `GitHub` readme to `readme.md`. Then we can add `readme.md` for the npm ignore `.npmignore` and add the `README.md` for gitignore `.gitignore`.
2. *(the more bad one)* Add `npm.README.md` and `git.README.md`. Remove the `npm.` or `git.` when commiting or publishing the git or npm.

Comment: but we want to keep both in repo. so .gitignore doesn't go here

Comment: Go for number 2 if you want to save them both in the repo

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on *why* you want to do this. Projects such as [libsquoosh](https://github.com/frostoven/Squoosh-with-CLI/tree/frostoven/libsquoosh) expose subdirectories as their own libraries while still importing them normally, resulting in this kind of structure:

```
├── cli
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── package.json
│   └── README.md
│
├── libsquoosh
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── .npmignore
│   ├── package.json
│   └── README.md
│
├── src
│   └── index.js
│
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

From within the main application in `src` you then import the lib normally via:
`import x from ../mySubdir/index.js`
But from external projects you import it as:
`import x from @namespace/mySubdir`
The `src` dir then isn't sent to NPM, only the two subdirs are, both with their own completely different README files. Meanwhile, the git root has yet a third README.

Note that each subdir has its own `package.json` and `.npmignore` files despite being part of a larger project.

This achieves the same effect as uploading something different to NPM than what you see in the git project's root, but adds clear hierarchical organisation for free.